# Is it possible to use the Javascript code of this HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html

This HTML is from a web page of a private IP address. I want to use the file validateReport.js in my Java application. How can I make a reference/call to it?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft FrontPage 4.0">
<meta name="ProgId" content="FrontPage.Editor.Document">
<title>Reports PM</title>
<style type="text/css">
  @import url(mpi.css);
</style>

<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" src="code/properties.js"></script>
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" src="code/commonTools.js"></script>
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" src="code/commonDate.js"></script>
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" src="code/menu.js"></script>
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" src="code/interval.js"></script>
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" src="code/usageDate.js"></script>
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" src="code/validateCommon.js"></script>
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" src="code/validateReport.js"></script>
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" src="code/calendar.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="setReportMenuInfo('Pm')"> 

    <div align="center">
    <center>
    <form name="reportPmForm" method="POST" action="/mos/fub.mpiproc?mirp" onSubmit="return validateReport(reportPmForm);">
        <table class=default height="100">
            <tr class=header1>
                <td width="100%" align="left" colspan="2" height="24">
                Market Participant Specific Reports</td></tr>
```

Also, in validateReport.js, this is an object variable declaration

`var mi = top.mimapi.document.applets.mpi;`

This object contains the method sendDownloadReportRequest which I want to use

```
if (msg == "") {
        busyOn (reportForm);
        a = mi.sendDownloadReportRequest (date,
                                          pub,
                                          market,
                                          submarket,
                                          type,
                                          pub,
                                          file);
        busyOff (reportForm);
        if (a) {
            alert("Report download request successful." +
                  "\nSee \"" + reportForm.FILE.value + "\" for details.");
        } else {
            msg += "          Download failed\n";
        }
    }

    return msg;
}
```

Is it possible to make a call/reference to this method in my Java application?

Comment: Essentially do you just want to request the report? Is it being requested over http/https? If so, what is the request sending, such as POST data, cookies, etc?

Comment: I essentially just want to request the report. Yes it is requested over https. Though it is a private ip which can only be accessed in our workstations. The data needed to request the report is the current date, report type, market. My java application will generate all the data mentioned. However, how can I make a reference to this sendDownloadReportRequest method?

Comment: Why call the method, why not just make the https request? (Still thinking on an answer)